# I was creating this Artificial Intelligence Based TacTic Toe Application

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, pylint

I was creating this Artificial Intelligence Based TacTic Toe Application in python  it was working perfectly but once I updated the python version it is showing an error with following message

(pylint) E0001: invalid syntax

here is the original code

```
def print_board():
x = 0
for i in range(0,3):
    print "  "+board[x]+ " | "+board[x+1]+ " | " +board[x+2]
    x+=3

    if(x<8):
        print"-----------"
    else:
        print
```

actual error showing up on this line only

```
   print "  "+board[x]+ " | "+board[x+1]+ " | " +board[x+2]
```

please help to fix

Comment: What version of Python did you update to?  If you went from 2 to 3, you'll need to wrap `print` statements with `()`.  Eg. `print(" ")`

Answer (score 2):

Pylint error [E0001](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:e0001) means that the syntax is invalid according to the Python interpreter. It's not really a linting error so much as an invalid program.

Print statements require parenthesis from Python 3 onward like so:

```
print("  "+board[x]+ " | "+board[x+1]+ " | " +board[x+2])
```

This will likely fix the E0001 error. While not strictly required, I'd recommend going a step further to make this code read a little more like idiomatic python code and use the string format function. This also has the side-effect of casting the values of board to strings which will prevent type errors if the contents of board are non-string.

```
print("  {} | {} | {}".format(board[x], board[x+1], board[x+2]))
```

If you're using python 3.6 or later you can go one step further and use the builtin format string syntax like so:

```
print(f"  {board[x]} | {board[x+1]} | {board[x+2]}")
```